# Is there any sort of permenant tracking spell or device in 5e? Could one be made?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I was wondering if tracking devices/enchantments could be made. They would be given to guild members so the guild could keep track of their mission progress, and help if they're in trouble.

Comment: Have you read the rules in the DMG for crafting items?

Answer (score 9):

### The item Crystal Ball

From the DMG (159), emphasis mine.

> The typical crystal ball, a very rare item, is about 6 inches in
> diameter. While touching it, **you can cast the scrying spell** (save DC
> 17) with it.

The scrying spell on PHB (273), emphasis mine.

> **You can see and hear a particular creature you choose that is on the
> same plane of existence as you**. The target must make a Wisdom saving
> throw, which is modified by how well you know the target and the sort
> of physical connection you have to it. **If a target knows you’re
> casting this spell, it can fail the saving throw voluntarily if it
> wants to be observed.**

You can use this item to spy on your *guildmates* as long as the NPC keeps *touching* the ball.

### A Warlock alternative.

As an alternative, if you want a more automatic response you can, instead of using a super rare item, create a NPC level 3 warlock. A warlock 3 with *Pact of the Chain* and *Voice of the Chain Master* can maintain a group and the Warlock always communicated. The *familiar "spy"* can deliver information as long as they are in the same plane of existence.

Voice of the Chain Master (PHB 111)

> You can communicate telepathically with your familiar and perceive
> through your familiar’s senses as long as you are on the same plane of
> existence.

### Homebrewing

If homebrewing is an alternative, you can create almost any magical item that your campaign **needs**. Being for thematically reasons or as a way to solve a particular problem, there is nothing in the rules that stops you (if you are the DM) to adjust as needed.

#### Retracting a decision

As the DM you have all the rights to retract a decision on your games. If a change suddenly seems more powerful than expected and its ruining everyone game, you can always take it back.

Comment: It's true there's nothing in the rules against homebrewing - in fact, there's a whole section to help, as KS pointed out. Probably good to point people there in that section of your answer.